# Is There Any Limit to How Wide 2 VHDL Numbers Can Be To Add Them In 1 Clock Cycle?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am considering adding two 1024-bit numbers in VHDL.

Ideally, I would like to hit a 100 MHz clock frequency.

Target is a Xilinx 7-series.

When you add 2 numbers together, there are inevitably carry bits. Since carry bits on the left cannot be computed until bits on the right have been calculated, to me it seems there should be a limit on how wide a register can be and still be added in 1 clock cycle.

Here are my questions:

1.) Do FPGAs add numbers in this way? Or do they have some way of performing addition that does not suffer from the carry problem?

2.) Is there a limit to the width? If so, is 1024 within the realm of reason for a 100 MHz clock, or is that asking for trouble?

Comment: Why not simply try it and see what the tools can manage?

Comment: No. You just need to choose a suitably long clock cycle. (At 1024 bits, I'd look at breaking the addition and pipelining)

Comment: @BrianDrummond can you move this to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You just need to choose a suitably long clock cycle.

Practically, though there is no fundamental limit, for any given cycle time, there will be some limit which depends on the FPGA technology.

At 1024 bits, I'd look at breaking the addition and pipelining it.

Implemented as a single cycle, I would expect a 1024 bit addition to have a speed somewhere around 5, maybe 10 MHz. (This would be easy to check : synthesise one and look at the timing reports!)

Pipelining is not the only approach to overcoming that limit.

There are also "fast adder" architectures like carry look-ahead, carry-save (details via the usual sources) ... these pretty much fell out of fashion when FPGAs built fast carry chains into the LUT fabric, but they may have niche uses such as yours. However they may not be optimally supported by synthesis since (for most purposes) the fast carry chain is adequate.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works, have not tried it:

```vhdl
library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Calculator is
  generic(
            num_length : integer := 1024
         ); 
    port(
            EN: in std_logic;
            clk: in std_logic;
            number1 : in std_logic_vector((num_length) - 1 downto 0);
            number2 : in std_logic_vector((num_length) - 1 downto 0);
            CTRL    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            result  : out std_logic_vector(((num_length * 2) - 1) downto 0));
end Calculator;
    
architecture Beh of Calculator is
    signal temp : unsigned(((num_length * 2) - 1) downto 0) := (others => '0');
 begin
 
    result <= std_logic_vector(temp);
 
    process(EN, clk)
        begin
            if EN ='0' then
                temp <= (others => '0');
            elsif (rising_edge(clk))then
            
                case ctrl is
                    when "00" => temp <= unsigned(number1) + unsigned(number2);
                    when "01" => temp <= unsigned(number1) - unsigned(number2);
                    when "10" => temp <= unsigned(number1) * unsigned(number2);
                    when "11" => temp <= unsigned(number1) / unsigned(number2);
                end case;
            end if;                 
    end process;
end Beh;
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. While I know how to perform the operation in VHDL, my question is, "Do FPGAs have a limit to the number of carry bits?" The VHDL language will let you add as many bits as you want. But what I really want to know is whether EDA synthesizers suffer from a carry bit limit?

Comment: I can´t exactly say how long the size limit is, but a long time ago i had the problem that the limit was exceeded. Maybe you will find some information in the user guides or simply try it in your IDE.